# Saving collections in Hibernate with Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring

I'm trying to save an entity that has a collection as a property that also has to be persisted in the database, so I have the following problem: if I save the instance before persisting the collection, I obtain the following error:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: asd.qwe.MyCollection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: ...

Otherwise, if I try to save the collections before saving my entity or if I set `cascade="save-update"` in the `list` definition, I would obtain this:

> Hibernate operation: could not insert: [asd.qwe.MyCollection]; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into entity_collections (fk_entity, field2, field3) values (?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1364]; Field 'fk_entity' doesn't have a default value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'fk_entity' doesn't have a default value

That's totally right, because 'fk_entity' refers to my entity that is not yet saved, and has a NOT NULL restriction.

I'm wondering why Hibernate tries to save collections before the actual entity? And.. is the a possibility to reverse the saving order?

Comment: Could you share your mappings. It sounds like something isn't quite right. If mapped correctly Hibernate will order the inserts to avoid foreign key violations as you rightly point out.

Answer (score 0):

You can config one to many mapping in your entity's hbm file, when you save the entity, Hibernate will save the Set into DB.

```
<set name="your_set" cascade="all">
    <key column="set_contact_column"/>
    <one-to-many class="your_set_class_name" />
</set>
```